# How can I make sure my access token to Instagram API does not expire?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a server that needs to pull the images that I have posted to my Instagram feed. I have read through the Instagram developer documentation and found out how to retrieve an access token.

My question - or doubt - is this: Is it possible to make sure that the access token does not expire? From reading the Instagram documentation it seems that the token will expire after 5000 queries. But I am not sure whether that is the case. So I am interested in hearing from anyone who has experience with the new Instagram API (the one where you need to get approved to get out of the sandbox) and who can tell me if the connections actually do expire or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you have to get a new one when the one you use expires:[Instagram OAuth API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: Darn. Not even if you are not doing any actions on behalf of other users than your own? I was hoping that there was a way to avoid having to have a manual process. ....

Comment: If you have server side application, you should be able to get access_token programmatically, you would have to store the client_ID and client_secret with your app though. See 'Server-side (Explicit) Flow' section of linked docs.

Comment: That is what I tried at first, but as far as I can see (and test), the server-side explicit flow returns an HTML page where I need to click an approval button. And since the HTML page seems to use Angular or something like that, I don't know how to parse that programmatically... But storing the Client_ID and Client_Secret within the app is not a problem for me.

Comment: @JoachimBøggild - have you solved that problem somehow?

Comment: No, sorry. I am no longer involved in the project.